# Describing a sitting posture

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm writing a book in English. Not my main language, but I'm doing this for fun mostly and love writing in English. I usually find words or descriptions on the internet if I'm not sure how to word something, but now I have to describe a sitting position, and I just can't find anything. It's the position of the girl on the left.

[image: Girls sitting]

It has been driving me a bit crazy. Is there any native English speaker out there that can help me describe this posture in such a way that it's easy to visualize for the reader?

Comment: Sitting position #7 [here](https://www.littlethings.com/sitting-positions-personality-test) is called **sidesaddle** (after the horse position) but I can't find any reference to back this up.

Comment: [***side-sitting***](https://www.healthline.com/health/baby/w-sitting#what-to-do) - *knees bent, both feet on same side of body*.

Comment: I found that exact same site :) But I've never seen it used that way, I don't want readers to go to Google and find a bunch of pictures about horses (there are no horses in the story :p).

Comment: Thanks Monica, that one is better indeed.
Question is, if I use it, will people understand it?

Comment: Yes, I just found "side sitting" with plenty of google images but FF was ahead.

Comment: @JonathanSmith welcome and please show your research next time, so others don't repeat what you already know. Please read [the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think it's the best of a bad bunch, in that we don't really have a name for this particular sitting posture. But I noticed an awful lot of hits for (apparently, highly undesirable) ***w-sitting*** when I did my search, and I admit I was fairly surprised to find that the "natural" extension to ***v-*** or ***u-sitting*** (as "w-sitting", but with both legs on the *same* side) has effectively ***no currency***. Even so, I'd expect anyone who actually *knew* what "double-u sitting" was would easily understand the nonce coinage "(single)u-sitting".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica there is another position which is also given the name **side sitting** in an answer to this [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338009/what-do-you-call-this-particular-sitting-position) that is actually sitting, in the sense that the sitter does not need any extra support... which was just reproduced below as I typed.

Comment: I think there's a *cultural* issue here (it's not just a matter of *language*). I know that many Asians are quite interested in how people sit -  particularly, *Japanese*, who even have a special word [***seiza***](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2006.html) for "formal kneeling". Anglophones in general are more interested in talking about the weather than discussing the merits of various "chairless sitting postures". But as in all cultures, "man-spreading" is generally acceptable, whereas that same posture is usually not acceptable for women, who *must* demurely cross their legs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a guide to the names of some sitting positions:

[image: sitting positions]

However, as a native British English speaker I can tell you that we don't use most of these terms in everyday conversation. We'd likely just say "sat on the floor", and then describe the position, for example, "...cross-legged".

Comment: So we would say "I sat cross-legged" or "I sat on my heels" or "I sat sideways". The posture indicated in the question isn't shown here.

Comment: As an AmE speaker, I’ve never heard of *any* of the terms in that image, though I could figure most of them out if I heard them. We simply don’t describe *how* someone sits often enough for there to be well known terms, aside from “with their legs/ankles crossed”.